# Relating a Character sum to a Gauss sum

Tags: number-theory, finite-fields, characters

Let $q$ be a prime power. Consider the mapping $f:(\mathbb{F}_q)^{\times} \to (\mathbb{F}_q)^{\times},$ where $x\mapsto x^2$. I was interested in sums of the form $$\sum_{t\in \mbox{Im}(f)} \psi_a(t)\quad (a\in \mathbb{F}_q),$$ where $$\psi_a(t)=\exp\Big( \frac{\mbox{tr}(at)}{p}\Big)$$ is an additive character of $\mathbb{F}_q$. I feel it should be possible to relate these sums somehow to the Gauss sums $$\sum_{t\in \mathbb{F}_q} \chi (t) \psi_{\beta}(t),$$ where $\chi$ is a multiplicative character and $\beta\in \mathbb{F}_q$. I can't seem to quite figure out how this should go.

Side Question: Do sums of this type have a name?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\eta$ be the unique character of order two  of $\Bbb{F}_q^*$ (= the Legendre character). Then for all $t\in\Bbb{F}_q^*$ we have
$$
1+\eta(t)=\begin{cases}2,&\text{if $t$ is a square,}\\0,&\text{if $t$ is a non-square.}\end{cases}
$$
So your sum takes the form
$$
S(a):=\sum_{t\in(\Bbb{F}_q^*)^2}\psi_a(t)=\sum_{t\in\Bbb{F}_q^*}\frac12(1+\eta(t))\psi_a(t).
$$
We know that $\sum_{t\in\Bbb{F}_q^*}\psi_a(t)=-1$, so we get
$$
S(a)=-\frac12+\frac12\sum_{t\in\Bbb{F}_q^*}\eta(t)\psi_a(t).
$$
You will recognize that last sum as a Gauss' sum related to the Legendre character.

Comment: I'm fairly sure this technique is described in detail in both Lidl & Niederreiter as well as Ireland & Rosen. It is a bread and butter trick to write the characteristic function of a multiplicative subgroup as a linear combination of characters whose restriction to that subgroup is trivial. In your case we applied this to the subgroup of squares.

Comment: Thanks! this is very helpful. I just ordered a copy of Ireland and Rosen's textbook. So in general, let $k$ be an integer such that $k\mid q-1$. Then the subgroup $H$ of $\mathbb{F}_q^{\ast}$ consisting of $k$ powers has order $(q-1)/k$. It's possible to express a characteristic function that vanishes on the complement of $H$ in $\mathbb{F}_q^{\ast}$. Should the general case look something like the following. $$\sum_{\chi } \chi (t)=\begin{cases} \phi(k) & t\in H\\ 0 & t\notin H\end{cases},$$ where the sum on the left is taken over all multiplicative characters with order dividing $k$ ?